# Convert value in a Spark dataframe column as another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe containing columns as (description, id) as below:

```
+----+---+
|desc| id|
+----+---+
|col1|  1|
|col2|  0|
|col3|  1|
|col4|  0|
|col5|  1|
+----+---+
```

I need to convert the description column contents as column names with id column contents as its values as:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  0 |  1 | 0  |  1 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I have tried with many ways to do this but in vain.

Spark 1.6.1 and scala 2.10.6

Any answers would be helpful at the earliest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pivot` function as below

```
df.groupBy().pivot("desc").agg(first("id"))
```

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for your timely reply.
Your answer worked like charm.